# Can't post to Twitter from Facebook

Tags: facebook, twitter

I have recently connected my business page @libertykalinah on FB to post automatically to Twitter @Libertykalinah but nothing seems to be posting through.

I can see people had this issue back in November, is this an issue again?

Answer (score 1):

From their [official support page](https://support.twitter.com/articles/31113-how-to-use-twitter-with-facebook):

> ### If your Tweets do not post:
>
> Make sure the box to Post your Tweets to Facebook is checked in your Twitter [Profile settings](http://twitter.com/settings/profile). Try disconnecting and reconnecting again.